# why the result comes out as 1, rather than 2, in this 8086 Subtract with borrow?

Tags: assembly, programming, 8086

```
STC
MOV AL, 5
SBB AL, 3 ; AL = 5 - 3 = 2, but I am getting 1 .. why?
RET
```

Comment: Read carefully the description of the SBB instruction, paying particular attention to how the carry flag is used.

Comment: Have you tried both with the carry flag set to 0 and with it set to 1?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows distinct lack of background research.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because asking people why something is broken *is* research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple really. [`sbb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sbb) is "subtract with borrow". It uses the CPU carry flag as the borrow flag. [`stc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stc) sets the carry flag, which means that `sbb` thinks there is a borrow and, instead of subtracting three from five, it subtracts four from five.

In this respect, the 8086 is the opposite of some other processors, notably the 6502 where `c=0` means there is a borrow, and `c=1` means there isn't a borrow.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the 6502 which inverts the carry as borrow, 8086 does not.